# ラズベリーパイでwebサーバーを立ち上げ外部ネットワークからアクセスしたいが、Google Nest wifiのポート転送設定が分からない。

Tags: node.js, apache, nginx, raspberry-pi

外出時にスマホから、自作のwebサイトへアクセスすることが夢なのですが、うまくいかず困っています。
特にポート転送のあたりに問題がありそうなので、ご助力いただきたいです。

Google Nest Wifiのポート転送ルールを設定しようとすると、下記手順が表示されます。

1. 端末のローカルIPアドレスを選択
2. 外部ポートを入力
3. 内部ポートを入力
4. TCP, UDP, TCP/UDPか選択

1は、固定したラズベリーパイのローカルIPアドレスを選択すればよいと思うのですが、
2, 3の意味が分かりません・・・。下記のように、様々なポートが出てきて混乱しています。

- httpならポートは80で外部と内部は揃える
- ラズパイのSSHはデフォルトでポート22が開放されている
- Node.jsで立てたサーバーは8000番のポートをlistenしている

ポート転送ルールを設定した後グローバルアドレスにアクセスすれば良いと様々な記事で描かれているのですが、そのときのポート(○○○.○○○.○○○.○○○:XXXXのXXXXの部分)はどれにすれば良いのでしょう？

ネットワークの基礎が分かっていないと思うので、良い参考サイトもあれば教えていただきたいです。

Comment: ポートって要するにネットワーク越しに何の機能を使うかってことです。あなたが使いたい機能が複数個ある場合には複数のポートを変換させるように設定する必要があります。どの機能がどのポートに対応しているかは調査してみてください（全部解説すると分量が多すぎて大変っス）

Answer (score 1):

web サーバでは http (80), https (443) がそれぞれデフォルトのポート番号として使用されています。
デフォルトのポート番号を使用した場合、ユーザーはブラウザのアドレス欄等で入力を省略することができます。

例:
`http://example.com:80`
↓
`http://example.com`

web サーバを不特定多数のユーザーに使ってもらうような場合には、http なら`80` を使用する方が便利です。
(https は証明書の取得が必要なので、ここでは割愛)

一方で、デフォルトのポート番号を使用していると悪意あるユーザーからの攻撃を試みるアクセスが発生しやすくなるため、利用者が限られているなら敢えて別のポート番号を使用することもあります。

参考:
[Webサーバは80番ポート以外使ってはいけないの？](https://ascii.jp/elem/000/000/458/458706/)